# Intermittent SQL Connection Issue using AAD token (MSI approach)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity

Facing an issue with Azure SQL authentication using Managed Service Identity of App Service. Its set up as mentioned in this article - [Azure-sql-auth-with-msi](https://winterdom.com/2017/10/19/azure-sql-auth-with-msi)

Everything was working fine for past few months but recently we started getting some intermittent errors when trying to open SQL connection:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

Earlier I suspected it could be something to do with some code changes. However, was able to reproduce it with simple web job whose sole responsibility is to get the token and open a SQL connection.

Wierd part is, its not failing continuously but randomly after certain intervals (2 out of 10 times). I tried to compare tokens for successful and failed attempts but do not see any difference in it.

Sample Web job code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection
{
    ConnectionString = "data source=<server>.database.secure.windows.net;
                           Initial Catalog=<db>;
                           Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True",
    AccessToken = new AzureServiceTokenProvider()
                  .GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result
})
{
    conn.Open();
    string cmdText = "SELECT SUSER_SNAME()";
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
    {
        object obj = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I've experienced a similar/them same issue with MSI. My theory, as I wouldn't know where to begin to debug this, is the MSI is rotated while the app is alive, but the MSI credentials are set as environment variables when the app is initially started. Which means periodically the app will try obtain a token with stale MSI credentials. The thin support I have for this theory is 1- it doesn't happen often, 2- doesn't occur due to heavy load, 3- it's a login error, 4- an app restart always fixes it, 5- MSFT docs state they rotate the MSI creds, 6- never got the error when using SQL credentials.

Comment: Thanks @PGHE for looking into it. Seems like it. Opened a ticket with MS but didn't get any satisfactory answer. Tried multiple restarts of an app but with no luck. Tried the scale up and scale down to see if that helps. It did resolve an issue for me atleast for now.